# Abstract classes/traits and invariant functions

Tags: generics, inheritance, scala, signature, variance

Given a trait `T`

```
trait T {
  def v: Int
  def +(t: T): T
}
```

the following class `A`

```
case class A(v: Int) extends T {
  def +(a: A) = A(v + a.v)
}
```

is not a valid subtype of `T`. The implementation of `A.+` is too restrictive, because it only accepts elements of type `A` whereas the signature of `T.+` requires all implementations to be able to accept objects of type `T` and not just objects of type `A`.
So far, so reasonable.

If I'd like to allow implementations of `T` to be that restrictive I can modify the declarations of `T` and `A` as follows

```
trait T[This <: T[This]] {
  def v: Int
  def +(t: This): This
}

case class A(v: Int) extends T[A] {
  def +(a: A) = A(v + a.v)
}
```

which obviously blows up the type signature.

Is there another way to declare that implementations of `T` only need to be compatible with objects of their own type?

**1st EDIT** In reply to [Landei's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438507/abstract-classes-traits-and-invariant-functions/4438883#4438883):

While self-types indeed shorten the current signature they don't shorten other signatures where `T` occurs, e.g.

```
trait C[D <: T[D], S] { self: S =>
  def +(perm: D): S
  def matches(other: S): Boolean
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use self-types:

```
trait T[S] {
  self:S => 
  def v: Int
  def +(t: S): S
}

case class A(v: Int) extends T[A] {
  def +(a: A) = A(v + a.v)
}
```

Comment: Please see my "1st EDIT" above. Thanks nevertheless, I did not consider self-type annotations before.

Comment: I don't know a general solution for this. Depending on your intentions and class hierarchy the type class pattern (using implicit) might be applicable (see Numeric for an example). Another try would be type variables (in order to pull D "inside" the trait).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with type members.  I don't know what brand of "short" you're after here exactly.  There is some redundancy, but on the other hand no type parameters passes big bracket savings on to you.

```
trait TT {
  type This <: TT
  def v: Int
  def +(t: This): This
}
case class AA(v: Int) extends TT {
  type This = AA
  def +(a: This) = AA(v + a.v)
}
```

Comment: The difference to my suggestion is that you can assign any subtype of TT to This. I think mhs wants to restrict This to the type of the class itself. However, how would the answer to the follow-up question (with trait D) look like with your approach?